# Encoding convert ä to Ã¤

Tags: r, utf-8

I am storing some character strings locally as UTF-8 and they might look something like "bären" I am then sending them off to the AdWords SOAP API to get some search volumes and I am being returned with something like this: "bÃ¤ren".

In R is there a way to get either "bären" to look like "bÃ¤ren" or vice versa so that I can "VLOOKUP"?

When I use the `Encoding()` function on "bären" it returns UTF-8 when I do the same on "bÃ¤ren" it returns unknown. If i then use the `enc2utf8()` function on the variable where "bÃ¤ren" is stored, it doesn't change what it is displaying but the `Encoding()` does then change to UTF-8.

When I don't use funky umlaut characters the API works just fine.

Comment: The problem is caused by how you use the AdWords API. It would therefore be helpful if you could show us what you’re doing.

Comment: So I am just using a package https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/adwordsR/index.html I am using the buildXmlEnvelope() followed by getXmlRequest() in order to generate a request.  Which seems to be working fine with the exception of the odd characters.

Comment: Well how are you parsing the returned XML? Does the XML string declare a correct encoding? If not, this seems to be a bug in the package (unfortunately its source code is quite messy and this might not be trivial to fix).

Comment: Not an expert here making this stuff up as I go along. If i export the returned xml it wont let me paste it in too long, but if i copy paste the returned queries they look like this: <queries>m奣hen</queries><queries>b峥n</queries><queries>k姥r</queries> (except that on my notepad++ it is returning xE4).

Comment: It does seem that iconv("bÃ¤ren",from="utf-8") returns what I am looking for.